# Probability - Domain of Expectation

Tags: expected-value

What is the domain of the expectation function for one deck (of 52 cards) with 10 independent variables for a blackjack game?

---

It's written in a paper that the domain of expectation of this problem is 33 million. But I just can't get why? Isn't the domain of expectation should equal to 52C10 which to 15.82 billion?

Comment: I think the point is that the suits are irrelevant, only the card values matter.  But it would be better to know exactly what it said in the paper.  Exactly what expectation value are they calculating?

Comment: "The domain of the expectation function for one deck had more than 33 million points in a space with 10 independent variables, corresponding to the 10 different card values in blackjack (for 8 decks it goes up to 6 x 10^15)" This is the exact sentence of the paper. I do think that only the card values matter, which means we have only 13 card values, but each value has 4 cards to be chosen. Then I'm stuck there